# Can't figure out the correct policy to initiate a Flask app with Elastic Beanstalk CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I have a Flask app. I have pip installed `awscli` and `awsebcli` packages. I ran `aws configure` command in my CLI and provided the credentials for the user I created.

According to [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.managed-policies.html), the `AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess` policy has been retired and I think now I am supposed to use the `AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk` policy.

So, I created an IAM user group `EB`. Gave it the the `AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk` policy. Created an IAM user also called `EB`. Attached the `EB` group to the `EB` user. Generated the keys and inputted them after entering `aws configure`

But when I try to run the command `eb init -p python-3.11 DukanApp` I get the error `ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. Access Denied`. What am I missing?

Below I have listed all the policies I get when I search "ElasticBeanstalk":

```
AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk
AWSElasticBeanstalkCustomPlatformforEC2Role
AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth
AWSElasticBeanstalkMaintenance
AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy
AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesServiceRolePolicy
AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
AWSElasticBeanstalkReadOnly
AWSElasticBeanstalkRoleCore
AWSElasticBeanstalkRoleCWL
AWSElasticBeanstalkRoleECS
AWSElasticBeanstalkRoleRDS
AWSElasticBeanstalkRoleSNS
AWSElasticBeanstalkRoleWorkerTier
AWSElasticBeanstalkService
AWSElasticBeanstalkServiceRolePolicy
AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier
```

Comment: I tried attaching the "AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk" policy directly to the user, instead of involving a group. Same result.

Comment: I just did. "Account" has correct value

Comment: Not sure where to check "UserId" and "Arn", but "Account" is definetly correct

Comment: I ran `eb init --debug` and the output was long, but one line that seems relevant "2023-11-13 22:18:39,444 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Directory found, but no config or app name exists"

Comment: I created a folder called "Dukan App". Inside I created a virtual environment called "env". Inside "Dukan App", next to "env" there is also app.py, templates folder, static folder, .ebignore file and requirements.txt

Comment: I am inside "Dukan App" when I run `eb init -p python-3.11 DukanApp` command

Comment: As u said now my user also has ec2 full access policy

Comment: I just ran `eb init -p python-3.11 DukanApp --debug` and again got a very long output

Comment: `awscli` and `awsebcli` is in a virtual environment and I have to activate the environment before using the `aws` or `eb` commands. Could that be causing issues?